# Why is there an extra label when classifier predicts from a test file?

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, scikit-learn, nltk

In a previous [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26602794/how-to-vectorize-bigrams-with-the-hashing-trick-in-scikit-learn/26629217?noredirect=1#comment42032677_26629217) i asked about text classification and i would like to understand better whats happening and how is working scikit-learn, Assuming that `train.txt` is

```
Pošto je EULEX obećao da će obaviti istragu o prošlosedmičnom izbijanju nasilja na sjeveru Kosova, taj incident predstavlja još jedan ispit kapaciteta misije da doprinese jačanju vladavine prava.
De todas as provações que teve de suplantar ao longo da vida, qual foi a mais difícil? O início. Qualquer começo apresenta dificuldades que parecem intransponíveis. Mas tive sempre a minha mãe do meu lado. Foi ela quem me ajudou a encontrar forças para enfrentar as situações mais decepcionantes, negativas, as que me punham mesmo furiosa.
Al parecer, Andrea Guasch pone que una relación a distancia es muy difícil de llevar como excusa. Algo con lo que, por lo visto, Alex Lequio no está nada de acuerdo. ¿O es que más bien ya ha conseguido la fama que andaba buscando?
Vo väčšine golfových rezortov ide o veľký komplex niekoľkých ihrísk blízko pri sebe spojených s hotelmi a ďalšími možnosťami trávenia voľného času – nie vždy sú manželky či deti nadšenými golfistami, a tak potrebujú iný druh vyžitia. Zaujímavé kombinácie ponúkajú aj rakúske, švajčiarske či talianske Alpy, kde sa dá v zime lyžovať a v lete hrať golf pod vysokými alpskými končiarmi.
```

and `test.txt` is

```
Por ello, ha insistido en que Europa tiene que darle un toque de atención porque Portugal esta incumpliendo la directiva del establecimiento del peaje
Estima-se que o mercado homossexual só na Cidade do México movimente cerca de oito mil milhões de dólares, aproximadamente seis mil milhões de euros
```

I have this little script that can perform language identification:

```
# -- coding: utf-8 --
import codecs
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB

train = []

#We set the classes
tags = ['bos','pt','es','slov']

word_vectorizer = CountVectorizer(analyzer='word')


#vectorize the train and the test files
trainset = word_vectorizer.fit_transform(
    codecs.open('/Users/user/Desktop/train.txt','r','utf8'))

testset = word_vectorizer.transform(
    codecs.open('/Users/user/Desktop/test.txt','r','utf8'))

# We train the algorithm:
mnb = MultinomialNB()
mnb.fit(trainset, tags)
res = mnb.predict(testset)

print res
```

And this is the output: `['es' 'pt' 'bos']`. The problem with the output is that clearly is adding one more class that actually is wrong (i.e. `bos`) to the classification output. I guess that the problem lies on how I'm tagging the `train` and the `test` files so, how can i tag both files in order to have the correct result?,  which is: `['es' 'pt']`.

By now i understand that both files need to be vectorized, but i dont understand what's happening here:

```
mnb = MultinomialNB()
mnb.fit(trainset, tags)
res = mnb.predict(testset)
```

Could anybody explain me deeply what happened above part of the script?.

Comment: What is ``len(codecs.open('/Users/user/Desktop/test.txt','r','utf8'))``? From what you say it should be 2 but according to the output it is 3.

Comment: If you check the test.txt file the file has two languages, spanish and portuguese. Hence the classes should be pt and es. (codecs.open('/Users/user/Desktop/test.txt','r','utf8')is the path of the test and train texts, they are in the desktop.

Comment: In the other hand i never use len() in the code above i used codecs.open('/Users/user/Desktop/test.txt','r','utf8')

Comment: Im using codecs for spelling symbols and punctuations in different languages.

Comment: Did you have an empty line in `test.txt`?

Comment: Yes, i didnt realize of it. Why does this twist the result?. Could you explain how is working the tagging and how is using scikit-learn the supervised learning aproach in this example?. Thank you @alvas!

Comment: Each line in the input file will be a separate training point. Which is why I asked you to report the number of samples using len.

Comment: @AndreasMueller, when predicting, is it right that the backoff for classifier is the most frequent class? and if the most frequent class is tied, the first class is selected?

Comment: Thank you very much guys for helping me to understand. The problem was the blank space @AndreasMueller you were right.

Comment: Still can't understand how does test.txt and train.txt were tagged, since in @alvas example he only defined the classes and only vectorize both (i.e. train and test). How does scikit train the algorithm and predict?.

Comment: @alvas what do you mean by backoff? If there are no features, the intercept (aka bias) is used. Which might select the most frequent class, but that is not guaranteed.

Comment: @ml_guy I don't understand your question.

Comment: @AndreasMueller I dont get how scikit learn classify, since in the example the ´train.txt´is not labeled (with ['bos','pt','es','slov'] clases). How does the learning is done in `mnb.fit(trainset, tags)`? and how does the classification is done in `res = mnb.predict(testset)` ?

Comment: @andreasmueller, yep i mean backoff. thanks for the info!

Comment: @ml_guy, although it's tedious, go through the scikit tutorial and you will learn many things on ML and also on the way learn how to use scikit http://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/

Comment: ``train.txt`` is labeled, there are four data points in hte training set and for labels in ``tags``.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an empty line that's causing an extra input in your `test.txt`

This line reads the `test.txt` line by line and change each line into your feature vector:

```
testset = word_vectorizer.transform(
    codecs.open('/Users/user/Desktop/test.txt','r','utf8'))
```

An additional empty line would have cause an extra vector that will be tagged by the most possible tag. In the training data `train.txt`, all labels are equally possible so the empty line will take the first label.

Answer (score 1):

I did some work with text classification and Scikit

```
mnb = MultinomialNB()        # Multinomial NB is initialized
mnb.fit(trainset, tags)      # Learning is done of the algorithm
res = mnb.predict(testset)   # Prediction is done with the trainset
```

I don't know why are you getting more that one record in prediction.
And what codecs what codecs module is working.
It a little bit awkard that you can set tags per line read.

And IMHO you should use stop words, by using them you will exclude a lot of "garbage".
Check more Scikit documentation, and there are materials about vectorization on the Internet.