# Classifying data from .arff files with scikit-learn?

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn, weka

In a [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26602794/how-to-vectorize-bigrams-with-the-hashing-trick-in-scikit-learn/26629217#26629217) i learned about the process to follow for classifying text with scikit-learn. In order to organize my data in a better way i discover .arff files let's say i have the following .arff file:

```
@relation lang_identification
@attribute opinion string
@attribute lang_identification {bos, pt, es, slov}
@data
"Pošto je EULEX obećao da će obaviti istragu o prošlosedmičnom izbijanju nasilja na sjeveru Kosova, taj incident predstavlja još jedan ispit kapaciteta misije da doprinese jačanju vladavine prava.",bos
"De todas as provações que teve de suplantar ao longo da vida, qual foi a mais difícil? O início. Qualquer começo apresenta dificuldades que parecem intransponíveis. Mas tive sempre a minha mãe do meu lado. Foi ela quem me ajudou a encontrar forças para enfrentar as situações mais decepcionantes, negativas, as que me punham mesmo furiosa.",pt
"Al parecer, Andrea Guasch pone que una relación a distancia es muy difícil de llevar como excusa. Algo con lo que, por lo visto, Alex Lequio no está nada de acuerdo. ¿O es que más bien ya ha conseguido la fama que andaba buscando?",es
"Vo väčšine golfových rezortov ide o veľký komplex niekoľkých ihrísk blízko pri sebe spojených s hotelmi a ďalšími možnosťami trávenia voľného času – nie vždy sú manželky či deti nadšenými golfistami, a tak potrebujú iný druh vyžitia. Zaujímavé kombinácie ponúkajú aj rakúske, švajčiarske či talianske Alpy, kde sa dá v zime lyžovať a v lete hrať golf pod vysokými alpskými končiarmi.",slov
```

I would like to experiment with scikit-learn and classify with a supervised aproach a complete new test string let's say:

```
test = "Por ello, ha insistido en que Europa tiene que darle un toque de atención porque Portugal esta incumpliendo la directiva del establecimiento del peaje"
```

Scipy [provide an arff loader](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.13.0/reference/generated/scipy.io.arff.loadarff.html), let's load an arff file with this:

```
from scipy.io.arff import loadarff
dataset = loadarff(open('/Users/user/Desktop/toy.arff','r'))
print dataset
```

This should return something like this: (array([]), how can use numpy record arrays to classify with scikit-learn?.

Comment: Unfortunately, the ARFF reader in scipy doesn't support the `string` attribute.

Comment: what about numeric atributes?. Does scikit support them?